# Cant generate Firebase audience by location

Tags: android, firebase

So, I have multiple cities as users, but I want only some cities to receive certain notifications

I have opened Firebase audiences but when creating one and selecting city , there is no my city there, I dont know how to get my city or generate the audiences for that city only

Comment: Basiclly you should create topic. When user get into app. You should subscribe your topic base on user city. And in firebase you can push by topic to notify group users

Comment: can you generate an answer on how to do that ? thanks

Comment: Are you have back end server to push notify? About client you can follow link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging to subscribe topic. Sorry currently I'm using mobile to reply. I only talk about the way you can solve it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help